# How to perform operations on date like "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M"?

Tags: r, datetime, format

I have 2 columns in my dataframe on which I want to perform operations like adding hours or adding days.

For example, I want to check if my date2 is in the range [date1 ; date1 + 30 days]

I've tried this :

```
  table(data$date1 <= data$date2 & data$date2 <= data$date1 + 30)
```

And I get this error :

```
  Error in data$date1 + 30 : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I transform my date1 and date2 in date format with:

```
  data$date1 <- substr(data$date1,1,16)
  data$date1 <- format(data$date1, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

Here is the head of my data :

```
     id1   id2            date2              date1
  1 CD0H   15741        2012/02/08 10:03    16/02/2015 16:22
  2 CD00   15058        2011/05/19 09:25    07/05/2015 10:39
  3 CHY0   15987        2011/01/20 11:58    06/02/2015 14:11
  4 CTPO   15254        2010/09/29 12:45    01/04/2015 04:49
  5 CDHY   15051                            06/05/2015 15:01
  6 CDJU   15035                            17/04/2015 08:56
```

Comment: how `data` looks like?

Comment: can you post `dput(head(data))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the transformation into Date/Time-objects does not work:

```
library( lubridate )

data <- read.table( filename, header=TRUE, sep = ";" )

data$date1 <- substr(data$date1,1,16)
data$date1 <- format(data$date1, format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")

data$date2 <- substr(data$date2,1,16)
data$date2 <- format(data$date2, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

The class is still 'character':

```
> class(data$date1)
[1] "character"
```

I did the transformation as follows:

```
library( timeDate )

table <- read.table( filename, header=TRUE, sep = ";",
                     colClasses = c( "factor", "numeric", "character", "character" ))

data <- cbind( table[1:2],
               apply( table[3], 2, FUN=function(x){ timeDate(x,format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M") } ),
               apply( table[4], 2, FUN=function(x){ timeDate(x,format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") } ) )

colnames(data) <- colnames(table)
```

This is more elaborate, but at least we have times and dates:

```
> class(data$date1)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
> (data$date1 <= data$date2 + as.difftime(4*365,units="days")) & (data$date2 <= data$date1 + as.difftime(30,units="days"))
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE    NA    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `lubridate` library for working with dates and times.

Here's how you'd add on 30 days using lubridate

```
library(lubridate)

ymd('2011-01-01') + days(30)
[1] "2011-01-31 UTC"
```

For more information:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/vignettes/lubridate.html

Comment: I tried to make it work with a ymd_hms but it does'nt work :

        > (data$date1)[c(1:5)]
        "2012/02/08 10:03" "2011/05/19 09:25" "2011/01/20 11:58"         "2010/09/29 12:45" ""                

        > (ymd_hms(data$date1))[c(1:5)]
        "2020-12-02 08:10:03 UTC" "2020-11-05 19:09:25 UTC"                  "2020-11-01 20:11:58 UTC"   NA  NA